# VBA code error file not found for shell command

Tags: vba, runtime-error, pdftk

I've tried many things to fix this error. Can anyone see why this code is saying file not found?

```
Sub PdfPwd()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim fTemp As String                                   'Defining Variables
    Dim oPdf As String
    Dim Pwd As String
    
    fTemp = "C:\Users\JSmith.ODINSU\Documents\" & "Temp.Pdf"
    oPdf = "C:\w2s\" & Sheets("w2 form").Range("q4").Value & ".pdf"                       'Set Path and Name for Protected Output PDF here.
    Pwd = Sheets("w2 form").Range("r4").Value                                         'Set appropriate Password here.
    
    With ActiveSheet                                      'Making a Temporary Unprotected Pdf file.
       .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                            Filename:=fTemp, _
                            Quality:=xlQualityStandard
    End With
    
'    fTemp = """" & fTemp & """"                           'Putting extra "" around for command Parameter.
'Debug.Print fTemp
'    oPdf = """" & oPdf & """"
'
'    Pwd = """" & Pwd & """"
                                                          'Making Command String for making protected PDFs Using PDFtk tool.
    cmdstr = "pdftk " & fTemp _
                      & " Output " & oPdf _
                      & " User_pw " & Pwd _
                      & " Allow AllFeatures"
Debug.Print cmdstr

    Shell cmdstr, vbHide                              'Executing PDFtk Command.
    
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)                 'Allowing 2 secs for command to execute.
    
    Kill Replace(fTemp, """", "")                         'Deleting temporary files.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    MsgBox "Finished", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

This is the file path i get.

pdftk C:\Users\JSmith.ODINSU\Documents\Temp.Pdf Output C:\w2s\10CARRACorrectedW2.pdf User_pw 123456 Allow AllFeatures

When I copy and paste that line into cmd and run it, everything works properly.

Comment: I'm going to assume it cannot find the file `pdftk.exe` - Try including the full path to the EXE file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally Figured it out. Here is the code that works. I excluded the end sub because I'm adding an email component to the code.

```
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Sheets("w2 form").Range("at6:at9")
    
    For Each cell In rng
    
    fTemp = "C:\" & "Temp.Pdf"
    oPdf = "C:\w2s\" & Sheets("w2 form").Range("q4").Value & ".pdf"                       'Set Path and Name for Protected Output PDF here.
    Pwd = Sheets("w2 form").Range("r4").Value                                         'Set appropriate Password here.
    
    With ActiveSheet                                      'Making a Temporary Unprotected Pdf file.
       .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                            Filename:=fTemp, _
                            Quality:=xlQualityStandard
    End With
    
    fTemp = """" & fTemp & """"                           'Putting extra "" around for command Parameter.
Debug.Print fTemp
    oPdf = """" & oPdf & """"

    Pwd = """" & Pwd & """"
                                                          'Making Command String for making protected PDFs Using PDFtk tool.
    cmdstr = "pdftk " & fTemp _
                      & " Output " & oPdf _
                      & " User_pw " & Pwd _
                      & " Allow AllFeatures"
Debug.Print cmdstr

    Shell cmdstr, vbHide                              'Executing PDFtk Command.
    
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)                 'Allowing 2 secs for command to execute.
    
    Kill Replace(fTemp, """", "")                         'Deleting temporary files.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem, it is actually the path of the program `PDFtk` causing the error. when you do it from `CMD` it catched the default path but when you do it with vba it follow the `MS Office` path that is whey it cannot find the application.

use this code:

```
cmdstr = "C:\Program Files\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe pdftk " ......
```

instead of

```
cmdstr = "pdftk " .....
```

OR

Copy the complete path of PDFtk.exe file (which could be found in `program files` folder) and paste it into code like above mentioned line.